# looping inside a html table and getting values of each td of each tr

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a table in html and i want to get value of each `td` of each `tr` using jquery, i'm unable to do it, as i'm not able to find how to do it, here is my table structure

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Ron</td>
        <td>28</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Mike</td>
        <td>31</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is this **the only table** in your real HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over all the rows and cells with [.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
$(function () {
    $('table tr').each(function () {
        $(this).find('td').each(function () {
            console.log($(this).text());
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$('table tr td').each(function(){console.log($(this).text())});
```